# What was the ship under construction initially called?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek Beyond, there was a ship under construction on the massive <strike>moon</strike> space station Yorktown. This ship is rechristened as the USS Enterprise-A (NCC-1701-A) after the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701) is destroyed. In the original timeline, the ship that became the USS Enterprise-A was the USS Yorktown, but in the new timeline, the space station is called the Starbase Yorktown instead. Of course, the original concept by Roddenberry for Star Trek had the ship named the Yorktown before changing it to Enterprise.

So what was the ship in Beyond originally meant to be registered and named? And is it also a Constitution class ship?

Comment: "In the original timeline, the ship that became the USS Enterprise-A was the USS Yorktown" - Are you sure? It wasn't mentioned in the movie. I can only find non-canon sources that claim it was the USS Yorktown originally, but some claim it was the USS Ti-Ho, others the USS Atlantis, and yet others claim it was unnamed.

Comment: @TheBloodyPoet TNG technical manual.

Comment: Ah. Reference manuals are a tricky subject as far as canonicity. Paramount considers them licensed and official but non-canon. Ronald D. Moore considers that specific book non-canon, and he produced TNG, but then again, it seems Roddenberry liked the idea, so I guess it may count as canon after all.

Comment: @TheBloodyPoet in any case, it would have had a planned name and registry number, in universe. It wasn't a planned replacement for the Enterprise after all.

Comment: What makes you think that the ship in this timeline was even supposed to be registered and named as something else in the first place, rather than just being planned as a new Enterprise-A right away? Is it explicitly said there that it was only rechristened as Enterprise-A? It seemed like they built it completely anew.

Comment: The ship was already under construction before the plot kicked off, according to Commodore Paris, when she sent Kirk off on the mission. Also, why would they replace a perfectly good 10 year old ship?

Comment: @cde Ok, I didn't notice that. It seemed like they constructed it at the end right away, in that fast forward montage.